# Show $ f(x) = (\frac{2x+1}{2x+2})^{ x+\frac{1}{2} } $ then $f''(x)f(x) > {f'(x)}^{2}$

Tags: derivatives

Function $f(x)$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$ as $f(x) = \left(\frac{2x+1}{2x+2}\right)^{ x+\frac{1}{2} } $.

problem is show that $f''(x)f(x) > {f'(x)}^{2}$

I was trying to get derivative of $f(x)$, but it was very hard and bored. How can I approach to show this inequality?

Comment: yes of course, but you will Need $$f''(x)$$!

Answer (score 2):

i have got $$f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2=1/2\, \left(  \left( 1/2\,{\frac {2\,x+1}{x+1}} \right) ^{x+1/2}
 \right) ^{2} \left( x+1 \right) ^{-2} \left( 2\,x+1 \right) ^{-1}
$$ and this is positive in the given interval

Comment: actually you computed it! How did you do that fast?

Comment: hm i have controlled it by my calculator with CAS

Comment: Thanks. but I wonder how to prove it without directly get derivative of f(x).

Comment: should i post the first derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: @MANMAID Using $$f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2=f(x)^2\left(\ln f(x)\right)''$$ that's not really hard.

Comment: With $z=x+\tfrac{1}{2}$, one has $\ln f(x)=z\ln \tfrac{z}{z+1/2}$, then second derivative is easy to obtain: $$ \frac{f''f'-f'^2}{f^2}=\frac{1}{z(2z+1)^2}$$

Comment: @ProfessorVector thanks, (my mistake!) I asked without doing the calculation.